# Horizontal Family tree with CSS and HTML - reversed

Tags: html, css

I've searched the web and foud a good example of family tree [here in codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdLeNe):

I want the same thing, but rotated 180 degrees. I want to start my family tree with 16 members and descending (16-8-4-2-1) left to right.

How can I achieve it by using/editing that code?
Stackoverflow says i need to accompany some code to my link, so I'm just pasting the HTML here.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"><span class="label">Root</span>
<div class="branch lv1">
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1</span>
  <div class="branch lv2">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1</span>
      <div class="branch lv3">
        <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-1-1</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2</span>
      <div class="branch lv3">
        <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-3</span>
      <div class="branch lv3">
        <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-3-1</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-2</span></div>
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3</span>
  <div class="branch lv2">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-1</span></div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-2</span></div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3</span>
      <div class="branch lv3">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-1</span></div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2</span>
          <div class="branch lv4">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2-1</span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2-2</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-3</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-4</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-4</span></div>
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-5</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still working on fixing the line curves but I got this to work by adjusting the css on the Codepen link you posted. I'll update the code/link as I improve it.

EDIT: Got it working! See the link and attached code. :
[image]
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVQXGg

```
//------- {{ Variables }} -------//

$white: #eee9dc;
$bg: #2e6ba7;

$horizontal-gutter: 100px;
$border-radius: 10px;

$entry-min-height: 60px;

$label-width: 150px;
$label-height: 30px;
$label-border-radius: 5px;


//------- {{ Styles }} -------//

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  color: $white;
  font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: $bg;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.branch {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: $horizontal-gutter + $label-width;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    width: $horizontal-gutter / 2;
    border-top: 2px solid $white;
    position: absolute;
    right: -$horizontal-gutter;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 1px;
  }
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: $entry-min-height;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 2px solid $white;
    position: absolute;
    right: -($horizontal-gutter / 2);
  }
  &:after {
    content: "";
    width: $horizontal-gutter / 2;
    border-top: 2px solid $white;
    position: absolute;
    right: -($horizontal-gutter / 2);
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 1px;
  }
  &:first-child {
    &:before {
      width: $border-radius;
      height: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: 2px;
      border-radius: 0 $border-radius 0 0;
    }
    &:after {
      height: $border-radius;
      border-radius: 0 $border-radius 0 0;
    }
  }
  &:last-child {
    &:before {
      width: $border-radius;
      height: 50%;
      border-radius: 0 0 $border-radius 0;
    }
    &:after {
      height: $border-radius;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $white;
      border-radius: 0 0 $border-radius 0;
      margin-top: -$border-radius + 1px;
    }
  }
  &.sole {
    &:before {
      display: none;
    }
    &:after {
      width: $horizontal-gutter / 2;
      height: 0;
      margin-top: 1px;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  }
}

.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: $label-width;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: $label-height - 5px * 2;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid $white;
  border-radius: $label-border-radius;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -($label-height / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried reversing HTML tags?
Change this:

```
  <div class="branch lv4">
        <div class="entry">
         <div class="branch lv5"> ....
```

For this:

```
  <div class="branch lv5">
        <div class="entry">
         <div class="branch lv4"> ....
```

I don't play it , but if you try maybe works.